# Water on Logitech M345 Wireless mouse

Tags: usb, wireless-mouse, logitech-mouse

I accidentally dropped water on it, and it seemed fine, so I continued using it. But after 20-30 minutes a red led light appeared on the mouse, and it stopped working.

Is there anything I can do, or do I have to buy another one?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any kind of limited warranty for the product?  You might be able to return it, depending on the policy of the place that you bought it from if it was a fairly recent purchase.

I'm not completely familiar with that particular model, but you can try a similar method that can sometimes work for cellphones:

1. Try and disassemble it to the best of your abilities (assuming it
   has some kind of visible screw present).
2. Submerge the mouse into a bowl of uncooked rice.  Try and get it so
   it's in the "middle" of the bowl, not sitting on top or below.
3. Let it sit for at least a full 24 hours.

The idea is that the rice will absorb the moisture contained in the device.

Here's a [link](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/how-to/tips/4269047) that advises on some additional details that I might have left out.  Although that linked article is referring specifically to cellphones, the basic premise is essentially the same and has saved one or two electronic devices of my own.

Comment: could i use a fan instead of the rice?

Comment: @Katie, you can try to use a fan.  The problem here though is that there will probably still be a lot of remaining moisture afterwords, meaning you might still experience frequent issues with it.  If it was only a very tiny amount of water it might work, I just can't guarantee that it will.  Besides, bags of white rice are fairly cheap, if you can spare 3-5$ it might be worth the investment.